# How to type text into Code Mirror line using selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, internet-explorer

I'm using IE to type in text into a text box that is labeled as a *CodeMirror-line*. I've tried javascript executor but that seems to only be for looks as when I try to save what I typed it disappears. How do I write text to the code mirror so it will stay? Below is the `xpath` I am using with the javascript executor to write to the Code mirror.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Some text';", element);

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='md-tab-content-1-0']/div/div/div[2]/jw-editor/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre")
    public WebElement element;
```

I've also seen something about using `setValue` to achieve this as well but haven't found a clear answer on how? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For selenium to detect the keyboard events, you'll first have to bring codemirror into focus.

You can do something like this:

```
/* getting codemirror element */
WebElement codeMirror = driver.findElement(By.className("CodeMirror"));

/* getting the first line of code inside codemirror and clicking it to bring it in focus */
WebElement codeLine = codeMirror.findElements(By.className("CodeMirror-line")).get(0);
codeLine.click();

/* sending keystokes to textarea once codemirror is in focus */
WebElement txtbx = codeMirror.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea"));
txtbx.sendKeys("Hello World");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for Java + Selenium. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Find the textbox using xpath and use sendKeys () method to enter text in textfield

> ```
> WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='md-tab-content-1-0']/div/div/div[2]/jw-editor/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre"));
> element.sendKeys("Some Text");
> ```

Comment: Please explain why your answer solves the problem... answers with simply "do this" don't help people to learn very well